# Batch-file get CPU temperature in °C and set as variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cpu, temp

How do i get a batch-file to work out the temperature of the Cpu and return it as a variable. I know it can be done as i have seen it been done. The solution can use any external tool. I have looked on Google for at least 2 hours but found nothing. Can any one help. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an example which keeps the decimal values and uses the full conversion value.

**Code**

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature /value') do set /a "HunDegCel=(%%~A*10)-27315"
echo %HunDegCel:~0,-2%.%HunDegCel:~-2% Degrees Celsius
```

**Output**

```
38.05 Degrees Celsius
```

Comment: Just adding here that not all hardware supports the query.

Comment: @foxidrive  Yep, that and the other items that Kevin lists in his answer are true.

Comment: +1 for better attention to detail in the batch code.

Comment: Thanks it works. May i ask waht is the update speed is.

Comment: It returns 2992 on my notebook, that is, 26.05 degrees Celsius, while some monitoring software shows 67.6 degrees Celsius, which is more likely since CPU is busy right now.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [wmic.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx):

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature
```

The output from `wmic` looks like this:

```
CurrentTemperature
2815
```

The units for `MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature` are tenths of degrees Kelvin, so if you want celsius, you'd do something like this:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%a in (
    'wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature /value'
) do (
    set /a degrees_celsius=%%a / 10 - 273
)

echo %degrees_celsius%
```

A few things:

1) The property may or may not be supported by your hardware.

2) The value may or may not update more than once per boot cycle.

3) You may need Administrative privileges to query the value.

Comment: When I run this I get 2982, which is 298.2 Kelvin 298.2-273=25.2 degrees C.  This is 77 degrees F which is way cooler than my CPU temp.  I'm pretty sure this is just giving me the room temperature not the cpu temperature.

Comment: I ran this and got the same 2815, which is 8.35c. That can't be right!

Comment: This is hardware-dependent and may or may not be accurate, but it's the best you can do from a batch file and built-in facilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you computer support it you can try like this :

```
 wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi PATH MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature get CurrentTemperature
```

This will output the temperature in degree Kelvin.

Comment: It actually returns tenths of degrees Kelvin. Also, the main/important part of his question is actually getting the output into a batch script variable, which isn't straightforward. Some likely ugly combination of `FOR`, `SET`, and `FINDSTR` will be needed.