# Windows CPU temps

Tags: windows, cpu, temperature

How can I check CPU temp from the command line in Windows 10?

I have an older computer that I installed a pre-assembled CPU cooler with radiator from Corsair, and I think that it is failing because I get CPU overtemp messages at reboot.  I realize that there are freeware apps that are capable of delivering this information, and I have installed the ASUS AI suite that goes with my motherboard and that is giving me the information that I want.  But it is a little infuriating that I have to install this software to get the temperature data.

I have found a script [at this link](https://gist.github.com/jeffa00/9577816) that runs in powershell that calls the temp and sets it to a variable like so:

```
function Get-Temperature {
$t = Get-WmiObject MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature -Namespace "root/wmi"
```

And I guess that WMiObject is supposed to return a temperature in (degrees Kelvin)*e+2, because later in the script it does conversions which return Kelvin, Celsius and Farenheit.  However, when I run it on my machine it returns 0 Kelvin and -273 Celsius and whatever that is in Fahrenheit.

I assume that something in that line is wrong?  Can you help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch-file get CPU temperature in °C and set as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004300/batch-file-get-cpu-temperature-in-c-and-set-as-variable)

Comment: Those freeware applications don't use WMI to access this information.  Generally the method is to use the `RDMSR` instruction ("Read Model-Specific Register") to access the data.  The details, such as the equation to turn the raw reading into a temperature, vary by processor family, which is why you see tools like OpenHardwareMonitor release new versions from time to time with no logic changes, just support for newly released processors.